# should i consider analytic branch for defining square roots to find this simple limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

What is the value of $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x-1}$. As $x$ goes to $0$, expression goes to $i$. I am confused.

Is the value $i$?

Answer (score 0):

```
should i consider analytic branch for defining square roots to find this
simple limit?
```

You certainly should. To see why, set:

$$w=x-1$$

and then define:

$$g(w)=\sqrt{w}$$

You are then looking equivalently at the limit:

$$\lim\limits_{w\to -1}g(w)$$

Now the above is a complex limit, so it exists provided the two following two limits exist:

$$\lim\limits_{\Re{w}\to -1}g(w)\,\,\,(1)$$

and

$$\lim\limits_{\Im{w}\to -1}g(w)\,\,\,(2)$$

The first limit (1) exists, provided you stay on the principal branch of the $g$ function and equals $i$, as you approach from the $x$-axis, from either direction.

The second limit (2) however does not exist, because this function has a branch point at 0 and a branch cut which extends from 0 to $-\infty$, so if you approach from above, it would be:

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}g(-1+\epsilon i)=i$$

while if you approach from below, it would be:

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}g(-1-\epsilon i)=-i$$

So the original limit does not exist, unless you are constrained on a specific branch.